# deleted constructor inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor

One of the requirements of constructor inheritance is that the derived class can not have any constructors with the same signature. I am unsure however about how deleted functions behave under these rules.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
    Foo() = delete;
    Foo(const Foo& a_Foo) = delete;
    Foo(int a_Value) : m_Value(a_Value) {}

    private:
    int m_Value;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
    public:
    using Foo::Foo;
    Bar() : Foo(7) {};
    Bar(const Bar& a_Bar) : Foo(12) {};
};
```

- Are deleted constructors inherited at all?
- If so, `Bar()` and `Foo()` have the same signature, does this make the code invalid?
- You could argue that `Foo(const Foo& a_Foo)` and `Bar(const Bar& a_Bar)`  have different signatures. How do copy constructors behave under constructor inheritance?

Comment: a default/copy/move constructor is never inherited, are you asking about deleted constructors in general, or only about those three?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Default, copy, and move constructors are *not* inherited, nor can inheriting a constructor implicitly declare a copy or move constructor for the derived class. Also, an inheriting constructor declaration will essentially just "skip over" a base class constructor if there's already a constructor with the same signature in the derived class.

> For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors other than a constructor
>   having no parameters or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter, a constructor is implicitly
>   declared with the same constructor characteristics unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same
>   signature in the complete class where the using-declaration appears or the constructor would be a default,
>   copy, or move constructor for that class.

([class.inhctor]/3)

Also, an inherited constructor is deleted if the corresponding base class constructor is deleted.

> A constructor so declared has the same access as the corresponding constructor in `X`. It is deleted if the
>   corresponding constructor in `X` is deleted (8.4). An inheriting constructor shall not be explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3).

([class.inhctor]/4)

Answer (score 2):

`Foo` constructor is deleted, so you can't define a constructor of class `Bar` that uses deleted `Foo` constructor. It doesn't make sense to talk about inheritance there, because you can never create an object of class `Bar` that uses deleted `Foo` constructor.

> Are deleted constructors inherited at all?

No. They are deleted, there is nothing to inherit from.

> If so, Bar() and Foo() have the same signature, does this make the
>   code invalid?

Default constructor can't be inherited.

> You could argue that Foo(const Foo& a_Foo) and Bar(const Bar& a_Bar)
>   have different signatures. How do copy constructors behave under
>   constructor inheritance?

Copy constructors can't be inherited as well.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki agree... was thinking about default only ctr. To be fixed

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, I would think that would work, but in this case there is no `Foo` ctor at all.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz I can see now one in OP's code, and that's how I had read the question before the edit took place

Comment: I made Foo constructable. The fact that the example specifically (which was meant to be pseudo code) does not work, doesn't awsner my question

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```cpp
class Symbol {
  public:
    Symbol() = delete;
    Symbol(char ch) : c{ch} {}
  private:
    char c;
    //
};


class Derived : Symbol {
  public:
  private:
    int i;
};


class NotDerived {
  public:
  private:
    int i;
};
```

The following line would not compile. You cannot create an object of a class with a deleted constructor. Everyone knows that.

```cpp
// Can't create an object because of deleted constructor.
Symbol sym;
```

However, you can create the object of the base class using the overloaded constructor:

```cpp
// Parametrized constructor, this one is fine.
Symbol sym_char('a');
```

The `Derived` class, using `: public` inheritance, inherits everything from the base `Symbol` class, including the deleted constructor. Indeed, if the `Symbol` class has a deleted constructor, disallowing you to create objects of that class using the default constructor, then logically the `Derived` class should also forbid you to create objects of that class using the deleted constructor.

```cpp
//  note: default constructor of 'Derived' is implicitly deleted because base class 'Symbol' has a deleted default constructor
//  The deleted consturctor is inherited from the base class.
Derived d;
```

The `Derived` class inherits all and any methods from the `Symbol` class, including any deleted constructors!

If you take away the inheritance statement, observe that the inherited deleted constructor disappears. There is no deleted constructor any more. Now the default compiler generated default constructor comes back, because the deleted constructor isn't overwriting it.

```cpp
// No deleted constructor: works
NotDerived nd;
```

The `NotDerived` class has a compiler generated default constructor, because it is not inheriting from anything. The `Derived` class does not have a default constructor, it has a deleted constructor, because it inherits from a class that has a deleted constructor.

So as we see in the above experiments, yes all and any methods that are in the base class **including deleted ones** get inherited into the derived class. This means that yes **deleted constructors** in base classes do get inherited into derived classes!